# Apache SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl

I have two files:

- **privkey.pem** that starts with `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`
- **cert.pem** that starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Now I should install them, but I never did this before and all related information I found ([1](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1225234-apache-http-server---ssl-certificate-installation), [2](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm), [3](https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-server-ssl-installation-instructions.html)) say, that I need three files:

- `primary.crt`
- `private.key`
- `intermediate.crt`

The file endings are different, but from what I found my `.pom` files are ok, too (only the content matters and I can rename the ending).
But what files do I have now? The primary and private? And do I miss some file? Or is it possible with only the two I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.crt
```

This should bring the site up on SSL. While this may work with some browsers, you'd require intermediate certificates for your certificate to chain up to the Root CA to ensure your site works in all browsers.

To obtain the intermediate certificates for your site, go to [What's My Chain Cert?](https://whatsmychaincert.com/?example.com) and enter you site name. This will indicate that you are missing intermediate certificates, as expected. Use the last form field on the page to generate the intermediate certs.

[image: Screenshot from What's My Cert Chain? showing area to download intermediate certificates]

Use the downloaded cert chain in the `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive in your Apache webserver config like this:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt
```

Once done, I suggest checking your site using an online scanner such as [SSL Labs server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to ensure your certificates are properly configured and that your configuration does not expose any vulnerabilities or SSL weaknesses.